# highlight an area of a graph and determine it's area in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, area

hi everybody i'm trying to highlight and determine the value of the negative and the positive areas on this graph:

```
    probe_02 <- data.frame(col1=probe_02_cv$Mean, 
                           col2=probe_02_cv_m, col3=probe_02_cv_M, col4=probe_02sd)
            xlabel <- "E [V]"
        ylabel <- "I[pA]"
        probe02 <- probe_02$col1 + outer(probe_02$col4, c(1,-1))
        with(probe_02, 
             plot(
               x21, ymean, type="l", ylim=range(probe02), ylab = ylabel, xlab = xlabel,
               panel.first=polygon(c(x21,rev(x21)), c(probe02[,1],rev(probe02[,2])),
                                   border=NA, col="#ebebeb")
             )
        )
polyarea(x = x21, y= ymean)
```

i want to highlight and compute the value of areas for which y<0 and y>0 inside the loop, while with polyarea i cant set a min and a max for y, it gaves me only the total area

!:https://preview.ibb.co/eeBfDw/probe_02_cv_mean.png

Comment: `object 'probe_02_cv' not found`

Answer (score 0):

not sure about highlighting but you can calculate the area using: https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/flux/html/auc.html

```
pos <- ymean > 0
flux::auc(ymean[pos], x21[pos])
flux::auc(ymean[!pos], x21[!pos])
```

hope this helps!